# Как передать данные из alertdialog на ту же страницу Flutter

Tags: flutter

Как передать данные из alertdialog на ту же страницу Flutter?

```
class MeasurementsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MeasurementsScreenState createState() => _MeasurementsScreenState();
}


class _MeasurementsScreenState extends State<MeasurementsScreen> {
  List<_ListItem> listItems;
  String lastSelectedValue;
  var name = ["Рост", "Вес"];
  var indication = ["Введите ваш рост", "Введите ваш вес"];
  TextEditingController customcintroller;

  void navigationPageProgrammTrainingHandler() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => ProgrammTrainingHandler()),
    );
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initListItems();
  }

  Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context, int indexAl){
    customcintroller = TextEditingController();
    if(indexAl < 2){
      return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(name[indexAl]),
          content: TextField(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            controller: customcintroller,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                fontSize: 18.5),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
              labelText: indication[indexAl],
              alignLabelWithHint: false,
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('ОТМЕНА'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('ОК'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(customcintroller.text.toString());
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
    } else if (indexAl > 1){
      navigationPageProgrammTrainingHandler();
    }

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Замеры',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,

          ),),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white ,
          onPressed:() => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: listItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index){
          return GestureDetector(
              child: listItems[index],
              onTap: () {
                  createAlertDialog(context, index).then((onValue){

                  });
              }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  void initListItems() {
    listItems = [
      new _ListItem(
          bgName: 'assets/images/soso_growth.jpg',
          name: customcintroller.text.toString().isEmpty == false ? customcintroller.text.toString() : "Рост",
          detail: "Нажми, чтобы добавить свой рост"),
      new _ListItem(
          bgName: 'assets/images/soso_weight.jpg',
          name: customcintroller.text.toString().isEmpty == false ? customcintroller.text.toString() :  "Вес",
          detail: "Нажми, чтобы добавить свой вес"),
      new _ListItem(
          bgName: 'assets/images/soso_chest.jpg',
          name: "Грудь",
          detail: "PRO-версия"),
      new _ListItem(
          bgName: 'assets/images/soso_shoulder.jpg',
          name: "Плечи",
          detail: "PRO-версия"),
      new _ListItem(
          bgName: 'assets/images/soso_biceps.jpg',
          name: "Бицепс",
          detail: "PRO-версия")

    ];
  }
}
class _ListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  _ListItem({this.bgName, this.name, this.detail});

  // final int index;
  final String bgName;
  final String name;
  final String detail;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 180.0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 1.0,
      ),
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                  image: new AssetImage(bgName),
                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.45), BlendMode.darken),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  alignment: Alignment.center),
            ),
            child: new SizedBox.expand(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      name,
                      style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 29.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                      child: new Text(
                        detail,
                        style:
                        new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Опишите свой вопрос более поподробнее, приложите ваш код. Суть вопроса не ясна. Что передать? Куда передать? Как передать?

Comment: Я хочу передать текст из TextField в TextView, который находится в айтеме Listview.

Comment: Добавьте код...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый лёгкий способ для вашего кода использование [Navigator.pop()](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics#3-return-to-the-first-route-using-navigatorpop), который будет передавать ваши данные обратно в TextView.

showDialog() может ожидать обратного вызова (с помощью async/await), и Navigator.pop() может передать значение обратно. Так что их можно соединить:

```
Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context, int indexAl) async {
   ...
   String returnVal = await showDialog(
       ...
   );
}
```

Затем, для возвращения данных мы используем:

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'MyData');
```

Готово мы вернули данные!

Comment: Не могли бы вы мне подсказать как это использовать на моем коде, просто я новичок в этом и много чего не понимаю.